# Laravel 5.4 specify files for npm run watch

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

The [Laravel mix docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) indicate that `npm run watch` will run "all relevant files for changes." But where do I see which files are relevant?

Specifically, I have some files in `resources/assets/js/components` that I'd like to have compiled. But say I had an arbitrary file that I also wanted to include.

How would one specify that?

**CLARIFICATION**

I may have not been clear enough in my original post, so I'll try again.

What I'm looking for is the list of files and/or directories that *TRIGER* `npm run watch` to (re)compile all assets; and how to edit that list.

Answer (score 0):

> where do I see which files are relevant?

All the files that were included in `webpack.mix.js` file.

> Specifically, I have some files in resources/assets/js/components that I'd like to have compiled.

Just add them in the `webpack.mix.js` file, for example:

```
mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/components/foo.js',
    'resources/assets/js/components/ba.js'
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

Once you edit them, webpack will compile your files in `app.js` file.

> But say I had an arbitrary file that I also wanted to include.

Same trick. Add it to `webpack.mix.js`, like as you require (css, js, vue, sass, less):

```
mix.styles([
'resources/assets/css/my-arbitrary-style.css'
], 'public/css/all-css.css');
```

**Note:** If you copy a entire dir, like:

```
mix.copyDirectory('resources/assets/js/components', 'public/js/components');
```

... using watch webpack will copy your components directory as `public/js/components/resources/assets/js/components`.

Comment: Hm,..I'm not sure that's quite correct. What you're describing is a way to specify which files I want to have `mix`-ed into the resultant `public/js/app.js` file. Which is great, and I do use that; and when `npm run watch/dev` commpiles, it already includes my `js/components/*.vue` files without me needing to specify that. But I tried what you said, and I added `'resources/assets/js/components/UsernameList.vue'`, it errored out with `There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing`. So it appears that the list of `watch`-ed files is somewhere else.

Comment: `There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing` it does look like laravel. Are you using `Angular`? cause this error is prompted where you make imports in wrong case sensive

Comment: Nope, not using Angular.  But again, a default L5.4 install already compiles in assets in `public/assets/js/components`, so there's no need to add them to `webpack.mix/config.js`.  My question is more about which files _trigger_ an `npm run watch`, and how to edit that list.  I'll update the question to be more specific.